# Converting Bootstrap Struts based application to an app

Tags: cordova, struts2, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-development, nativeapplication

We have a Struts2, JSP, Bootstrap and jQuery based responsive UI.

The current demand is for an App.

Is there any quick way to convert the Web Application itself into an App? I know this is a bit generic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking sounds to our ears like:

> We have a car, V6, 4WD, fueled by petrol.
>
> Is there any quick way to convert the car into a motorcycle ?

No need to be a scientist to answer that...

An App needs to be written in the language(s) used by its target platform(s) (Swift on iOS, Java on Android, etc..).

There are frameworks out there (Ionic, Sencha Touch, etc...) that wrap the underlying complexity by allowing you to write simple HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript, at the cost of some speed if confronted with a Native App.
An App written like this is called Hybrid App.

Far from being an *easy* way, it is however an *easier* way than rewriting everything, if you're not strictly performance-oriented.

To stick with the previous example, it means that you'll keep two of the four tires of the car, some of the other parts, and will "just" need to adapt them into something brand new, crafted from scratch.

Here you can find a [list of frameworks for creating Hybrid Apps](http://noeticforce.com/best-hybrid-mobile-app-ui-frameworks-html5-js-css). Good luck with that.

Comment: *"I know this is a bit generic, but response would be appreciated"* : no sings of appreciation have been shown until now, BTW.